# Asp.Net core MVC Area routing not working as expected

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an application in which I want to use Area. But routing is not working as expected.

I have an Area called **Admin**

[image]

I have the following code in a startup.cs configure method

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();

                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                 name: "areas",
                 areaName: "Admin",
                 pattern: "{area}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
               );

            });
```

when I create an anchor tag using following code routing doesn't work

```
 <a class="nav-link" asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Admin</a>
```

it gives me following url when the application runs

> https://localhost:44321/?area=Admin

what is the issue? why proper url is not generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you. I use this for my .net core 3.1 project and it work well, without any troubles.

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
               name: "AdministratorArea",
               areaName: "Administrator",
               pattern: "Administrator/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}"); //This is Administrator route. You can you {id} and other parameters which you want

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}"); // This route is for Controllers which are situated in project controller folder
        });
```

Comment: yes, it's working. Can you explain the change for my understanding?

Answer (score 2):

You also got the right code.. Just make sure your new AreaControllerRoute is up above the default one.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                    name: "areas",
                    areaName: "Admin",
                    pattern: "{area}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            });
```